# Issue with upgrade to Polymer 0.5.1 and styling paper-dialog

Tags: css, polymer, styling

So I just updated my project from Polymer v0.4.2 to v0.5.1 of the Polymer library.  One thing that seemed to have changed is how the *paper-dialog* element is implemented.

In v0.4.2, when I had a *paper-dialog* inside of my custom element, I could customize it with CSS inside of my element using *core-style* elements.

In v0.5.1, if I understand correctly, the *paper-dialog* is no longer implemented inside my component, but instead it's implemented in the *core-overlay-layer* element which is in the html page **outside** of my component.

So does that mean that I now have to add a CSS style sheet to the html page that contains my component?  If so, then I can no longer use *core-style* along with the benefits of the *CoreStyle.g* object.  It also means that everything related to my component is no long **all** encapsulated inside of my component.

Please tell me that I am wrong and that there is a way for me to style the paper-dialog from within my component still.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Polymer 0.5.1 the `layered` property (doc: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-overlay) defaults to `true` which allows it to always display above page content. If `layered` is false, the dialog may not display on top if there is something after it in DOM with a higher stacking context.

However because `layered` reparents the dialog to a global `core-overlay-layer` it's not possible to style it from an outer scope. There are a couple options for styling:

1. If you know you don't have any DOM with a higher stacking context than the dialog, set `layered="false"` to get the non-layered behavior and you can style it from the outer scope.
2. Style the dialog with a `/deep/` rule in a global style. You can still use `core-style` by referencing the style in the global scope. You can also include it in the same file as your element definition, e.g.

```
<core-style id="x-dialog">
  html /deep/ #dialog {
    color: red;
  }
</core-style>
<core-style ref="x-dialog"></core-style>
<polymer-element name="my-element" noscript>
<template>
  <paper-dialog id="dialog"></paper-dialog>
</template>
</polymer-element>
```

3. Extend `paper-dialog` and style the new element:

```
<polymer-element name="my-paper-dialog" extends="paper-dialog" noscript>
<template>
  <!-- or use core-style -->
  <style>
    :host {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</template>
</polymer-element>
```

Live examples: http://jsbin.com/subanakuna/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Yvonne, Thanks for your response!  I think I will try extending the paper-dialog with my own element.