# Extending PaperDialog and calling toggle() via Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to extend PaperDialog so that I can style it. I'm attempting to use method 3 from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26954690/337415), but with Dart instead of JS. Here's my component.

```dart
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_dialog.html">

<polymer-element name="hc-dialog" extends="paper-dialog" noscript>
  <template>
    <link href="hc-dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <shadow></shadow>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

The component appears to render correctly into the DOM - and I can verify that it functions correctly by adding opened="true" to the component - this renders great for example:

```dart
<hc-dialog opened="true" closeSelector="[dismissive]" transition="paper-dialog-transition-bottom">
  <div layout horizontal>
    <span flex></span>
    <paper-button raised dismissive>Done</paper-button>
  </div>
</hc-dialog>
```

But I don't want it auto-showing, and the issue comes when trying to find a way to call toggle() on this component via Dart. In the solution linked above ([working JS Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/subanakuna/1/edit?html,output)), it's called via JS:

```dart
<script>
  Polymer('x-dialog-3', {
    toggle: function() {
      this.$.dialog3.toggle();
    }
  });
</script>
```

However if I try to achieve the same thing in dart, I'm unable to retrieve a component that has the toggle() method on it:

```dart
shadowRoot.querySelector('hc-dialog').toggle();
```

results in Object.noSuchMethod. Inspecting the returned object via reflection makes that clear:

```dart
var he = shadowRoot.querySelector('hc-dialog');
var cm = reflect(he).type;

while (cm != null) {
   print(cm);
   cm = cm.superclass;
}
```

gives:

```dart
ClassMirror on 'HtmlElement' (:1)
ClassMirror on 'Element' (:1)
ClassMirror on 'Node' (:1)
ClassMirror on 'EventTarget' (:1)
ClassMirror on 'NativeFieldWrapperClass2' (:1)
ClassMirror on 'Object' (:1)
```

==> My Dialog is not a PaperDialog/CoreOverlay, which is why I can't call toggle() on it.

What's wrong with this approach? How do I go about getting something I can call toggle() on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymer.dart core- and paper-elements are just wrappers around Polymer.js elements. Extending is not supported for these kind of elements becaus a Dart class can't extend a JS class.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if I'm missing something here. One of the big advantages of polymer is the promise of libraries of web components that can be imported and extended. Have I understood right that if I use Polymer-Dart then the world of components developed in JS won't be extensible? Is this limitation documented anywhere? Either here: https://www.dartlang.org/polymer/faq.html#differences-between-the-javascript-and-dart-versions-of-polymer or here: https://www.dartlang.org/polymer/using-elements/ would be good candidates. Do you know if this is something that will change in the future?

Comment: Ok I found this: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20388 - wondering though if this problem isn't as big as it seems to me at  the moment. Kind of a deal breaker.

Comment: For my very specific use-case, I can hack around this by using: shadowRoot.querySelector('hc-dialog').setAttribute('opened', 'true'); - as noted above, the component is completely functional - I just can't find a way to access the methods (e.g. toggle())

Comment: Sorry - that only works once. This works repeatedly: shadowRoot.querySelector('hc-dialog')..setAttribute('opened', 'false')..setAttribute('opened', 'true');

Comment: How does you current code look like. I assume you don't extend paper-dialog anymore.

Comment: Yes I still extend paper-dialog - my code is identical to that posted in the question (note the noscript declaration - I have no dart code backing my component implementation). The only difference is that instead of trying to call "shadowRoot.querySelector('hc-dialog').toggle()", I am now calling "shadowRoot.querySelector('hc-dialog')..setAttribute('opened', 'false')..setAttribute('opened', 'true')" - everything seems to work fine - this is because setAttribute() is a method on HtmlElement, whereas toggle() is not. I get all the dialog styling benefits I was seeking via this implementation.

Comment: caveat: this route means I don't appear to have a way to call dialog methods on my new component. It would be great to see documentation on the approach the Dart authors used to wrap JS components (for core- and paper-), as this seems a manageable approach - write my new dialog in JS, and then wrap it via the same mechanism. I did start to take a look at that, but was getting a little too bogged down in the details. Maybe that's the next step if I find a need to access the methods.

Comment: This package generates the wrappers https://github.com/dart-lang/api.dartlang.org. It relies partially on proper comments in the elements JS source.

Comment: Thanks Günter. Interesting that Polymer 0.8 will also only support extending native elements, although custom element extension is listed as a todo. https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/0.8-preview/PRIMER.md#type-extension